# ¡Invocando a todos los twitteros de SOes!

Tags: discusión

espero se encuentren bien, ¡es viernes y el cuerpo lo sabe!

En esta ocasión me gustaría invitar a todos aquellos que andan por **Twitter**, a que compartan sus perfiles en esta sección a modo de respuestas para agregarlos a una lista exclusiva:

https://twitter.com/fredyfx/lists/la-hermandad-de-soes

La idea es conocernos mejor, en especial entre quienes usamos esta red social, varios andamos por la sala de chat de manera seguida y bueno, la hermandad va creciendo cada vez más y más, entre todos compartiendo conocimiento.

He agregado a la lista varios usuarios que conozco por estos lares, gente que aprecio, admiro y que sigo en Twitter. Sé que hay muchos más por conocer, venga, colaboremos para tener un espacio donde estemos todos juntos :D

¡Que tengan un excelente fin de semana!

Con cariño,

Su hermano @fredyfx.

Comment: Acá el mio `https://twitter.com/itsHivat` un saludo!

Comment: https://twitter.com/emielpez hola! :)

Comment: twitter.com/lordofwisdom :D

Comment: twitter.com/L_carrera por acá :D

Comment: https://twitter.com/jachguate

Comment: ¿Qué se gana exactamente con esto?

Comment: Socializar más, conocernos entre los usuarios que andamos por aquí :D

Comment: la idea es buena, pero no muchos ocupan twitter, tal vez puedan hacer lo mismo pero en facebook

Comment: twitter.com/elporfirio

Comment: Me uno a la lista. Mi cuenta: https://twitter.com/hechigames

Comment: twitter.com/Goerman_Rafi

Comment: Ahí va el mio.  https://twitter.com/Neftali_German

Comment: El mío [ssivasquez](https://twitter.com/ssivasquez), no hablo de tecnologías en mi red social, pero si soy participe de esta red https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: normal mi estimado, la cosa es socializar más entre todos :D

Comment: Con algo de retraso... aquí va el mío: [alvaro_montoro](https://twitter.com/alvaro_montoro).